# SQL select query using group by

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, group-by

How to get the TeamCount and TeamLead Name currectly

```
  Teams | TeamCount | TeamLead Name
-------------------------------------
| Team1 | 2         | NULL
| Team2 | 2         | NULL
| Team1 | 1         | Prashanth
```

Some times Team may or may not have the team lead. 
So we just have to show the TeamLead name as null, 
if team lead is not found for the team

I need some help to get the out as below

```
Teams | TeamCount | TeamLead Name
---------------------------------
Team1 | 3         | Prashanth
Team2 | 2         | NULL
```

Comment: Go read about outer join

Comment: This question isn't too clear. What are the tables you want to get the info from? What is the query you are currently running?

Comment: this question is fine.  Let me think about a solution

Comment: select distinct  T.Name,(CASE WHEN TM.IsLead = 1 THEN TM.TName ELSE null END) TL from
TeamMembers TM 
JOIN Teams T
ON TM.TeamId = T.Id

Comment: i am running the above query.

Comment: Hi friends any answer..please...

Comment: @user2366302: I did it in SQL Server too, let copy and see the result. Hope this help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

MySQL:

```
select team as teamId, sum(teamcount) as teamcount,
  (select teamleadname from teams
   where teamId = teams.team and teamleadname is not null
   limit 1) as teamleadname
from teams
group by team
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5889d/39

SQl Server:

```
declare @teams TABLE(Team varchar(20), TeamCount int, TeamLeadName varchar(20));

INSERT INTO @teams
VALUES
    ('Team1', 2, null),
    ('Team2', 2, null),
    ('Team1', 1, 'Prashanth')

select l.Team, l.TeamCount, r.TeamLeadName
from
    (select Team , sum(TeamCount) as TeamCount from @teams group by Team) as l 
    left outer join 
    (select Team, TeamLeadName 
    from 
        (select Team, TeamLeadName, row_number() over(partition by Team order by TeamLeadName desc) as roworder 
        from @teams) as o where o.roworder = 1
    ) as r
    on l.Team = r.Team
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: But here team count is not comming

Comment: @user2366302: I did it in SQL Server too, let copy and see the result. Hope this help. :)

Answer (score 0):

...and here you go!

```
     create table test2 as
            select distinct c.teams,sum(c.TeamCount) as SUM,c.TeamName
     from
           (select a.Teams,a.TeamCount,b.TeamName from team as a
     left outer join
           (select * from team where TeamName ne "") as b
            on a.Teams = B.Teams) as c
     group by c.Teams;
```

You should try to develop these solutions by working from the inside out and build the query in steps

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a LEFT OUTER join between `Team` and `TeamMembers`, and including the `IsLead` into the join criterion, before grouping by the Team name - this will exclude non-leads:

```
SELECT T.Name, MIN(TM.TName) AS Lead
FROM Teams T
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TeamMembers TM 
    ON TM.TeamId = T.Id AND TM.IsLead = 1
GROUP BY T.Name;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aeb34/3)

The `TeamCount` doesn't seem to make sense here - if you can elaborate on how you intend deriving it, perhaps we can help here

PS : You've tagged both MySql and Oracle - don't do this please.

Comment: Here i want TeamCount under the teamlead, which includes team lead also. Is it possible?

Comment: Your query is too good. Thanks very much. Can you please help me to get the team count also.

Comment: You haven't shown us your table structure. Is TeamCount a column on table TeamLead? Is it derived as the count of teams from another table?

Comment: No, We have to calculate the teamcount from the Teammember table based on the teamid.

Comment: Hi friend did you found any solution for this.